# How to deal with dots (.) in column names in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to load a local csv file into SparkR, which contains dots in column names. After reading the file I tried to change the names and replaced "." with "_". Still I am not able to do any operation on the created SDF. 
Here is the reproducible code:

```
#writing iris dataset to local
write.csv(iris,"iris.csv",row.names=F)

#reading it back using read.df
iris_sdf<-read.df("iris.csv","csv",header="true",inferSchema="true")

#changing column names
names(iris_sdf)<-c("Sepal_Length","Sepal_Width","Petal_Length","Petal_Width","Species")

#selecting required columna
head(select(iris_sdf,iris_sdf$Sepal_Length,iris_sdf$Sepal_Width))
```

Running this piece of code I am getting following error:

```
16/08/24 13:51:24 ERROR RBackendHandler: dfToCols on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to resolve Sepal.Length given [Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:134)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$cl
```

What should I do to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a dot, SQL syntax thinks you are referring to a table. If it is a column containing a dot, you need to place back ticks around the name

```
"`your.column`"
```

Comment: True but when I have already replaced all the 'your.column' to 'your_column' - Then it shouldn't refer to 'your.column' again in backend.

Comment: I don't think the line that changes the column names actually did change them. At least, according to the stacktrace

Comment: Looks like that's the case... even I've tried your suggestion using backticks (before column name change)

Still it is giving the error- Error in select(iris_sdf, Sepal.Width) : object 'Sepal.Width' not found

Comment: You might have to strip the header from the CSV using Spark, then apply a schema over the dataframe. I haven't played around too much with the CSV reader in Spark 2.0 to know how to handle the dots in the column names

Comment: @cricket_007 As far as I remember providing schema should be enough without removing header.

Comment: I just meant that I don't know if `header="true",inferSchema="true"` options will deal with the dots in a special way, or not.

Comment: @MohitBansal you should comment on the other answer to respond to someone else

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround here is providing schema for reader:

```
schema <- structType(
   structField("SepalLength", "double", FALSE),
   structField("SepalWidth",  "double", FALSE),
   structField("PetalLength", "double", FALSE),
   structField("PetalWidth",  "double", FALSE),
   structField("Species",     "string", FALSE))


head(read.df("iris.csv", "csv", header="true", schema=schema))
##   SepalLength SepalWidth PetalLength PetalWidth Species
## 1         5.1        3.5         1.4        0.2  setosa
## 2         4.9        3.0         1.4        0.2  setosa
## 3         4.7        3.2         1.3        0.2  setosa
## 4         4.6        3.1         1.5        0.2  setosa
## 5         5.0        3.6         1.4        0.2  setosa
## 6         5.4        3.9         1.7        0.4  setosa
```

Comment: this helped, but what if we have 100 or more columns? Is there any better way to create schemas?

Comment: You can create one programmatically from codebook if you have one. Schema inference is bad anyway.

Comment: I am new to SparkR, is it possible using SparkR?

Comment: Standard R functions should be more than enough.